# vertical align two divs within a relative div but float one to the right

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to use display: inline-block; more often. I have two divs or images or whatever at inline-block level. I am vertically aligning them at middle. However, I would like to have one float left, and one float right - which breaks the spell. For example: a logo in a header on the left and a mobile navigation symbol on the right. I might as well just say that absolute positioning is not an option:

[A FIDDLE is here:](http://jsfiddle.net/nouveau_io/GLtxn/)   Thanks.

HTML

```
<header class="global-header">
    <div class="logo">logo</div>    
    <div class="hamburger">☰</div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

html, body {
    margin: 0;
}
.global-header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.logo, .hamburger {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #f06;
    padding: 1em;
}

.logo {
    width: 12em; height: 5em;
}

.hamburger {
    width: 3em; height: 3em;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of addressing this is to use text-align:justify. For this to work, the content needs to be more than one line long, so we have to add a second line of content using the :after pseudo-element. Then it's all about stopping the second line taking up any vertical space.

Add this to your css:

```
.global-header {
    text-align:justify;
    line-height:0;
}

.global-header:after {
    content: '\A0';
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
    line-height:0;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/RZsyx/

Depending on what you are really putting in the logo and hamburger elements, you may need to apply a line-height to each of them.

Comment: Can you tell me a little about the '\A0' ? - I have been just leaving it a blank space, but have seen all sorts of new ways of dealing with that.

Comment: `\AO` is the CSS escape for the Unicode code point for No Break Space - equivalent to the HTML entity reference `&nbsp;`. We need to have a character on the line that's going to be rendered for CSS to create the line box. This character can't be a normal space, because normal spaces will get removed from the rendering if there's nothing else on the line. But we don't want to *see* any character, so a no-break space fits the bill nicely. Other non normal spaces, such as an em-space would work just as well.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I look foreword to putting this into place and seeing how it goes.

Comment: Well, it works. Thanks. There is some undesired space between the inline block elements. Here's what we ended up with: http://codepen.io/nouveau/pen/tgAbi

Comment: SO. I was trying to put this in production and it was not working. The culprit was a clearfix I had on the .inner-w - So if anyone has a similar issue, check to see if that might be it. -dw c/o nouveau

Answer (score 2):

Would the following give the desired result?

`.hamburger {
    width: 3em; height: 3em;
    position:relative;
    left:100%;
    margin-left:-15em;
}`

The -15 comes from hamburger width + logo width

Comment: That is pretty awesome. The only problem is that if you change any of the variables it breaks... so it has the same restraints as a margin-top or something. However, it's the best idea so far. It holds up well when zooming in and out as well. Imagine a "theme" and the user changes the image though... hmmm... I'll mark it as answered if I don't get something better today. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to do a header for a mobile page.
you should try to use the box-model with box-orient and box-flex.

a good guide can be found here (it s in german though):
http://www.html5rocks.com/de/tutorials/flexbox/quick/

at the bottom is some kind of CSS-fiddle-box, so you can try if it
is the right choice for you.

the only drawback I can think of, is that you have do fill in another 
element between `.logo` and `.hamburger` which gets the `box-flex: 1`.

leading you:

```
<header>
   <div class="logo boxes">logostuff</div>
   <div class="fill boxes"></div>
   <div class="hamburger boxes">E</div>
</header>
```

with the following (additional) css

```
.boxes {
   display:-moz-box;
   background:#ff0000;
}
.global-header {
   float: none;
   display:-moz-box;
   -moz-box-orient:  horizontal;
   -moz-box-align: center;
}
.fill {
   -moz-box-flex:1;
}
```

Comment: Other draw backs include browser compatibility, the need to use old flex box and new flex box simultaneously, and the spacer div you speak of.

Comment: sorry, I got the impression, you work with html5 and css3, so you would have to deal with those drawbacks already. the `header` tag implies at least browser compatibility. By the way, 'less' is a nice tool, to implement aliases for the browser specific css3 tags.

Comment: There is a myriad of simple ways to deal with html5 compatibility but not flexbox. http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/ - and yes, I use the most up to date versions of html and css. We are currently using SASS and compass. LESS is cool too, I just think that SASS is more widely used and more likely to be standard when passing off projects.